# Action doesn't get fired on signalr hub when using websockets over load balancer, SSE or any other method works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr, signalr-backplane

I have a signalr hub setup for a chat function using Signalr version 2.4.0.  A SQL backplane is used and setup in the standard way as the site is across two servers using a cloud load balancer from Rackspace.

Using Server Sent Events there is no issue, messages are sent over the load balancer without a problem.  When using websockets the onConnected and onDisconnected are called normally and a connection is made.  I've enabled signalr logging on the browser and can see no errors or issues.  However when a hub action is called from the browser i.e. hub.server.sendaction();, in this instance to send a message (although it applies to any action being fired other than connect or disconnect) nothing at all happens.  The action doesn't get fired, there is no error anywhere it seems.

Taking the load balancer out of the equation seems to resolve the issue, the action is called and the message is sent to the other user.

Can anyone speculate as to what the problem here?  I've enabled every form of logging I could come across and I can't see any errors or issues.  According to the signalr logging a websocket connection is established normally.  I can see in the log the hub action is being invoked correctly.  Clearly the load balancer must be involved somehow but seeing as there is no issue with SSE and no errors I have no real idea as to why the action is not getting called?

Edit - As requested, this is the hub, contents of action not included as the action is simply not firing.  There is an onConnected and onDisconnected method, both fire as normal:

```
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
      private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

      public void Send(int ChatID, string UserID, string message, string 
      name, string profileImage)
      {
          //Stuff happens here but it is not being fired at all
      }
    }
}
```

Relevant javascript on page:

```
$(function () {
var note = $.connection.notificationHub;
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

            $(document).on("click", "#sendmessage", function () {
            note.server.send('@Model.ChatID', '@Model.UserID', $('#message').val(), '@Model.Name', '@Model.ProfileImage');
            msgArea.scrollTop = msgArea.scrollHeight;
            $('#message').val('').focus();
        });
$.connection.hub.qs = { 'name': '@Model.Name', 'UserID': '@Model.UserID', 'connectionGroup': '@Model.ChatID' + '_hub', 'cohortName': '@Model.Cohortname', 'outlog': 'in' };
});
```

Comment: Can you provide (as succinctly as possible) the javascript code and the hub and the action you are calling?

Comment: Hello there, I've added the relevant action in the hub and javascript code on the page.  Please bear in mind that according to the Signalr logging the send action is being invoked.  I haven't included the onConnected and onDisconnected as both work fine.  The send action appears before these in the hub though.  There is more javascript on the page relating to the hub but again, not really relevant.

Comment: To emphasise, this works perfectly fine using websockets locally and also live when not over the load balancer.  There are also zero issues with any of this using SSE or ForeverFrame over the load balancer.

Comment: You are making a connection, but no response message is occurring.   It could be a number of issues 1)  The query in the request is not correct 2) The server is not returning any message 3) The connection is closing 4) The response is being returned but you code is not getting the response.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check which failure is occurring.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the input.  There doesn't appear to be an issue with the query because it works fine with other transports or using websockets without the load balancer.  The signalr logging states that a websocket connection is established and also logs the invoking of the Send function.  I will give wireshark or fiddler a go and see if I can uncover anything.

Comment: How is your loadbalancer operating? if it isnt set to sticky, and you cant ensure that the same hub gets the response, the connection cant be maintained. I discussed this in may with daniel roth @ the MS Build

Comment: @Isparia - The load balancer is currently set to maintain session persistence which I believe means it's sticky?  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Rob i did read a bit about your load balancer and session persistent should be the right way to go, what you could try is to disable the caching from the load balancer, also make sure the load balancer does nothing else. i also would suggest to run only a single instance for now behind the load balancer, until you get this to work, when it works, add a second instance and test again. 
Im out of Ideas after this, so i wish you best of luck